# How to get the area of ImplicitRegion 3d object

Tags: regions

```
ImplicitRegion[z >= x^2 + y^2 && x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 6, {x, y, z}] // RegionBoundary // Area
```

This code returns `20.23041621162892` which isn't a symbolic number. So how to calculate it without use some math transformations?

> It takes longer than 2 min but without returning a result in 11.3

Answer (score 5):

Just split the steps.

```
ImplicitRegion[
  z == x^2 + y^2 && x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 6, {x, y, z}] // Area
```

gives

$$
\frac{13 \pi }{3}
$$

```
ImplicitRegion[
  z >= x^2 + y^2 && x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 6, {x, y, z}] // Area
```

gives

$$
-4 \left(\sqrt{6}-3\right) \pi
$$

[image]

Comment: In Mathematica v12(Windows64)  your version is much slower (32s) than the version @wuyudi intends to speed up (0.4s) !

Comment: @UlrichNeumann ,thx for pointing out that, RegionBoundary seems not so useful in this case.

Comment: And this two results add up to $20.531\dots$ instead of $20.236\dots$

Comment: @wuyudi No , the `RegionBoundary`-version seems to be much faster!

Comment: @SneezeFor16Min You changed the content of your question. Now you are looking for an answer v12.1 instead of 11.3?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Not mine!

Comment: @SneezeFor16Min sorry!

Comment: @wuyudi  You changed the content of your question. Now you are looking for an answer v12.1 instead of 11.3?

Comment: Your Q worries about timing, but you give no evidence, neither before nor after.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Because 11.3 didn't run it out. It keeps running for a long time so I cancel the calculation. So I can't use the AbsoluteTiming to show the time. Meanwhile, I find 12.1 can run this , but the result is not what I want. Maybe I did change the question... sorry.I would change the title.

Comment: @wuyudi I usually say something like "I let it run for 10 minutes and then aborted it."  It wasn't clear what "really slow" meant.  Sometimes it's 1 second (compared to a millisecond, that's really slow) and so on.

Comment: @wuyudi I don't have V11.3 any more, so I can't check.  What happens if you run `Area[reg, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]`?  I think the difference might be WRI decided to default to machine precision in V12.0/12.1

Comment: @MichaelE2 `Area[ImplicitRegion[   z >= x^2 + y^2 && x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 6, {x, y, z}] //   RegionBoundary, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]` doesn't give result either. It run 195s and $Aborted.

Answer (score 5):

For semialgebraic regions we can express the boundary as disjoint pieces through the third argument of [`CylindricalDecomposition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CylindricalDecomposition.html#37191583). We can then find the area of each piece and sum.

```
OrList[HoldPattern[Or][args__]] := {args}
OrList[expr_] := expr

expr = z >= x^2 + y^2 && x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 6;

bdcomps = OrList[BooleanConvert[CylindricalDecomposition[expr, {x, y, z}, "Boundary"]]];

acomps = With[{reg = ImplicitRegion[#, {x, y, z}]},
  If[RegionDimension[reg] == 2, Area[reg], 0]
] & /@ bdcomps;

Simplify[Total[acomps]]
```

> ```
> (49/3 - 4Sqrt[6])π
> ```

Comment: What is the version of mma? I run this code in 11.3, returns 0 https://imgur.com/a/wfwJ9aT . In wolfram cloud, https://imgur.com/a/1mLkNs4 . in tio.run , https://imgur.com/a/FIVGMM5

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo. It should be fixed now.